# Hyperledger Fabric: What is the default enrollment.profile used by fabric-ca-client?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

The [Fabric-ca-client](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clientcli.html) page does not mention what is the default `enrollment.profile` used by fabric-ca-client.

```
$ fabric-ca-client enroll --help
Enroll identity with Fabric CA server

Usage:
  fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://user:userpw@serverAddr:serverPort [flags]

Global Flags:
      --caname string                  Name of CA
      --csr.cn string                  The common name field of the certificate signing request
      --csr.hosts stringSlice          A list of space-separated host names in a certificate signing request
      --csr.keyrequest.algo string     Specify key algorithm
      --csr.keyrequest.size int        Specify key size
      --csr.names stringSlice          A list of comma-separated CSR names of the form <name>=<value> (e.g. C=CA,O=Org1)
      --csr.serialnumber string        The serial number in a certificate signing request
  -d, --debug                          Enable debug level logging
      --enrollment.attrs stringSlice   A list of comma-separated attribute requests of the form <name>[:opt] (e.g. foo,bar:opt)
      --enrollment.label string        Label to use in HSM operations
      --enrollment.profile string      Name of the signing profile to use in issuing the certificate
      --enrollment.type string         The type of enrollment request: 'x509' or 'idemix' (default "x509")
  -H, --home string                    Client's home directory (default "/Users/sjain68/.fabric-ca-client")
      --id.affiliation string          The identity's affiliation
      --id.attrs stringSlice           A list of comma-separated attributes of the form <name>=<value> (e.g. foo=foo1,bar=bar1)
      --id.maxenrollments int          The maximum number of times the secret can be reused to enroll (default CA's Max Enrollment)
      --id.name string                 Unique name of the identity
      --id.secret string               The enrollment secret for the identity being registered
      --id.type string                 Type of identity being registered (e.g. 'peer, app, user') (default "client")
  -M, --mspdir string                  Membership Service Provider directory (default "msp")
  -m, --myhost string                  Hostname to include in the certificate signing request during enrollment (default "WITSC02X6385JGH")
  -a, --revoke.aki string              AKI (Authority Key Identifier) of the certificate to be revoked
  -e, --revoke.name string             Identity whose certificates should be revoked
  -r, --revoke.reason string           Reason for revocation
  -s, --revoke.serial string           Serial number of the certificate to be revoked
      --tls.certfiles stringSlice      A list of comma-separated PEM-encoded trusted certificate files (e.g. root1.pem,root2.pem)
      --tls.client.certfile string     PEM-encoded certificate file when mutual authenticate is enabled
      --tls.client.keyfile string      PEM-encoded key file when mutual authentication is enabled
  -u, --url string                     URL of fabric-ca-server (default "http://localhost:7054")
```

We would like to know:

- what is the default `enrollment.profile` used by fabric-ca-client?
- and how does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 profiles by default with the Fabric CA:

```
signing:
    default:
      usage:
        - digital signature
      expiry: 8760h
    profiles:
      ca:
         usage:
           - cert sign
           - crl sign
         expiry: 43800h
         caconstraint:
           isca: true
           maxpathlen: 0
      tls:
         usage:
            - signing
            - key encipherment
            - server auth
            - client auth
            - key agreement
         expiry: 8760h
```

The difference between them are the key and extended key usages.  The default profile (used for enrollment) issues certificates for digital signatures.

The ca profile is for root certificates (allows you to sign certificates).

The tls profile is for TLS ... note that it does not include digital signature as a usage